# PHP show text up to /*show more text*/

Tags: php, string, html-lists, explode

I would like to only show the text that is before `/*SHOW MORE TEXT*/` However I am unsure how to do such a thing because my text is like this:

```
<ul>
<li>show this</li>
<li>show this</li>
/*SHOW MORE TEXT*/
<li>don't show this</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried

```
$texts = explode("/*SHOW MORE TEXT*/", $text);
```

But the issue with this is then it won't fix the `</ul>`

How can I fix this small issue?

Comment: When you are talking about hiding the text on the client side (web browser) than this is out of topic for `php`, you have to look for a `javascript` solution. If this is _not_ what you are trying to do then please edit your question and make more clear what the exact behaviour is you are looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with Jquery toggle functions it's more easier and faster. Here you find details: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Because we don't use jQuery and all this data is stored in our DB

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is as follows:

Don't include ul tags in the text string, and then use explode and take the first element of array using array[0] and close `</ul>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Using php you can do this like

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<?php 
if(condition is true){
  echo "<li>text will be displayed if condition is true otherwise it will not displayed</li>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

using javascript you can use

```
<li style="display:none;">this will not visible</li>
```

Comment: I get this will work, but the same text needs to show in our shop area of the site we use the text from our products content area. I was thinking maybe making another column in our DB and call it feature_content. - I guess thats the easier way

Comment: try to avoid redundancy in db,

Comment: You can handle this in your php code, with simple if else condition.

Answer (score 0):

you can use display:none; property for that and later when you need it you can display it using java script.

```
<li style="display:none;">don't show this</li>
```